How can I hide bullet symbol on table of contents frames in Beamer?
I'm working on a Beamer presentation and need to customize the appearance of the Table of Contents (TOC) frames. Specifically, I want to ensure that bullets do not appear in the mini-frames when the TOC is displayed.
As is:

To be:

Here's a simplified version of my document:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\AtBeginSection[]
{   \begin{frame}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection]
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
\section{Section1}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} Sample text \end{frame}
\section{Section2}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} Sample text \end{frame}
\begin{frame} \frametitle{Sample frame title} Sample text \end{frame}
\end{document}

In the above code, I use the following code to add the TOC to the beginning of each section:
\AtBeginSection[]
{   \begin{frame}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection]
    \end{frame}
}

